# APPLY Strong to Buffer rule. Quit Switching Bit rates MPEG DASH

Tags: google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I am using mpeg dash for adaptive bit rate streaming of video from my server.

I have used ffmpeg and MP4Box to generate 4 different quality video files from my source .mp4

The .mpd file generated has the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.5.1-DEV-rev5619  on 2015-07-14T11:07:18Z-->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500000S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H3M1.42S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
  <Title>test/test.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>
 </ProgramInformation>

 <Period duration="PT0H3M1.42S">
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="1920" maxHeight="1080" maxFrameRate="24" par="16:9" lang="und" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
   <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64000d" width="320" height="240" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="375715">
    <BaseURL>400_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="904-1403">
      <Initialization range="0-903"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
   <Representation id="2" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.640015" width="420" height="270" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="644824">
    <BaseURL>700_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="905-1404">
      <Initialization range="0-904"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
   <Representation id="3" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001f" width="1024" height="576" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="1349484">
    <BaseURL>1500_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="905-1404">
      <Initialization range="0-904"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
   <Representation id="4" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001f" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="2264379">
    <BaseURL>2500_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="905-1404">
      <Initialization range="0-904"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
   <Representation id="5" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.640028" width="1920" height="1080" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="3633049">
    <BaseURL>4000_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="906-1405">
      <Initialization range="0-905"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

I am using video.js along with dash.js to playback the mpeg dash content on client side. The issue is that the video doesn't playback perfectly when i simulate network conditions from chrome dev tools.

It works at times and it doesn't at others. For ex the stream starts with bit rate of 400kbps and then detects enough bandwidth available so it switches to 2500kbps. Then when i bring down my bandwidth to 400kbps again then the video freezes at some point of time.

At times the video freezes after few initial seconds of playback when it tries to switch the stream. I think there might be some command line parameter that i am missing while generating my video files via ffmpeg or generating .mpd file via MP4Box.

below are the commands i use for ffmpeg and MP4Box

```
ffmpeg -y -i inputfile -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ab 128k -c:v libx264 -r 24 – g 24 -b:v 1500k -maxrate 1500k -bufsize 1000k -vf "scale=-1:720" outputfile.mp4


MP4Box -dash [DURATION] -rap -frag-rap -profile [PROFILE] -out [path/to/outpout.file] [path/to/input1.file] [path/to/input2.file] [path/to/input3.file]
```

Also while i am generating .mpd files via MP4Box i am getting below warning in console

```
[DASH]: Files have non-proportional track layouts (320x240 vs 420x270) but sample size and aspect ratio match, assuming precision issue
[DASH]: Files have non-proportional track layouts (320x240 vs 1024x576) but sample size and aspect ratio match, assuming precision issue
[DASH]: Files have non-proportional track layouts (320x240 vs 1280x720) but sample size and aspect ratio match, assuming precision issue
[DASH]: Files have non-proportional track layouts (320x240 vs 1920x1080) but sample size and aspect ratio match, assuming precision issue
```

Whenever the video stops playing the chrome console has these logs

```
Number of times the buffer has run dry: 25
Apply STRONG to buffer rule.
Quit switching bit rates.
```

I don't have any clue as to why the buffers run dry and it stops switching the bit rates.

Anything that is predominantly wrong in the process ?

Comment: Do you have the content available for testing, e.g., a link to an MPD? Would like to test it with our bitdash player. Additionally, to exclude encoding errors you can generate content with www.bitcodin.com, its free for the first 6GB of output, and we can test again.

Comment: here is the my source mpd along with the mp4 files with different bit rates

http://scrum.shreeapp.com/mpd/

I cannot set the CORS header on the server and hence you wont be able to play the mpd directly but you can download the mp4 files and the mpd and check them locally...

Comment: We do not support segment base content at the moment. You can generate segmenttemplate content then it should work if your encoding steps are correct. That's possible with MP4Box and bitcodin.com too.